# Unable to connect to ODBC through shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, odbc

I build a r shiny app which uses the odbc library to fetch the data from server hosted in public server and shows the result output. It is working perfectly under Win10.

I am using the below code to connect to server:

```
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "SQL Server Native Client 11.0",
                 Server = "****",
                 Database = "****",
                 UID = "****",
                 PWD = "****")
```

When I hosted the app in www.shinyapps.io it is not working. It shows the error as below:

```
Warning: Error in : nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: 01000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0' : file not found
```

I am unable to why it says 'file not found'? The app works perfectly when I run the app using rstudio from my PC.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Sumanta

Comment: Error message is pretty clear, you have SQL server driver installed on your computer but not on shinyapps site. If you have root access, install a driver and configure `odbc.ini` file. If you don't have root access, I recommend making JDBC connection and supplying jar file for your app.

Comment: You have to use the RODBC package since this is installed on the shinyapp.io server. See [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/225408367-Connecting-to-databases-using-RODBC-on-shinyapps-io) for more infos

Comment: @AlexanderLeow, I have update the code as below
`library(RODBC);
con <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};
                         server=****;
                         database=****;
                         Uid=****;
                          Pwd=****;
                         ')`
It is working fine in my PC, but from shinyapps I am getting the below error:
`[RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found
`
This time I am using the 'SQL Server' driver, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use FreeTDS. I found either using 7.4 or 7.0 version.

try this using odbc:

```
    library(DBI)
    library(odbc)

    con <- dbConnect(
      odbc(),
      Driver      = "FreeTDS",
      Database    = database,
      Uid         = uid,
      Pwd         = pwd,
      Server      = server,
      Port        = 1433,
      TDS_Version = 7.4
    )
```

or this usind rodbc:

```
    library(RODBC)

    con <- odbcDriverConnect(
      'Driver=FreeTDS;
      TDS_Version=7.4;
      Server=<server>;
      Port=<port>;
      Database=<db>;
      Uid=<uid>;
      Pwd=<pw>;
      Encrypt=yes;
      TrustServerCertificate=no;
      Connection Timeout=30;')
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, I have tried all the possible combination as suggested for ODBC and RODBC with FreeTDS v7.4 and v7.0. However none of them working. I am putting the error log below:
`shinyapps[723104]:   [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 0, message [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
shinyapps[723104]:   [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 20013, message [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unknown host machine name.`
Please help.

Comment: The error message is somehow good, because it shows that the drivers where found now. The problem is the host now, you can try to check host name and port.